# Multiple field comparison in Rails where clause

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a cleaner, DRYer, way to write this in Rails 5.0 using Postgres as the DB?

```rb
CrmRevenueLineItem.references(:crm_account)
.where("crm_accounts.name ILIKE :qry OR crm_accounts.legal_name ILIKE :qry 
        OR crm_accounts.website ILIKE :qry", qry: wildcard_query)
```

I feel like I'm repeating myself a lot in there. It was worse before I learned about named parameters (the `:qry`) and was using `?` as the placeholder.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I always list those out too :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit shorter variant using [concat_ws](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function

```rb
CrmRevenueLineItem.references(:crm_account)
.where("CONCAT_WS(' ', crm_accounts.name, crm_accounts.legal_name, crm_accounts.website) ILIKE :qry", qry: wildcard_query)
```